# SubDomain ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i need to create a sub domain in the web site when ever a new user is registered in my site.his user name wil be used as subdomain in the site

As the user will fill the member forms and will become the member , he will get a url like
http://subdomain.domain.com  automatically,
i need to create the subdomain using ASP..NET MVC (C#)

i have no idea about subdomain creation dynamically , 
if you have any idea about subdomain creation programmatically or having any general idea plz help me.

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821993/dynamic-subdomains-in-asp-net-mvc   Basically you're looking to create a dynamic subdomain for your site.

Comment: i tried this but i was not able to complete my task, any sample application would be very appreciated.